# HTML Zoom into Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, frontend

I am working on a collaborative drawing website that allows users to paint on a synced canvas together. The painting and synchronization functionalities are working great. However, I encountered an issue with pixel blurriness when zooming in on larger paintings.

Here's a simplified version of the canvas and zooming code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
/* Zooming */
transform: scale(5); /* 5x zoom */
```

And here how I draw the pixels (currently in black only):

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleCanvasClick(event) {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = Math.floor(event.clientX - rect.left);
    const y = Math.floor(event.clientY - rect.top);
    const color = '#000000'; // Change this to the desired color

    // Update the canvas on the client-side immediately
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);

    // Send the pixel update to the server
    socket.emit('updatePixel', { x, y, color });
    }
```

Upon zooming in, the pixels become visibly blurry, and I hope someone has a method, that maintains the original pixel quality when zoomed in.

One idea I had was using a 2D plane in 3D space instead, adjusting the viewer's position to get nearer or further away from the plane. This way, the pixels maybe won't get blurry. However this seems kinda too complex, and there is probably a simpler alternative.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried the other way round? Drawing a 5x5 square and scaling down to 0.2? Alternatively you’ll need to redraw on a zoom.